# js fullscreen toggle button goes to fullscreen but won't exit it

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function tied to an onclick event of a button. It should check to see if the documentElement it should toggle full screen mode and swap the button image.

```
function toggleFS() {
    var fsmode = (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !==     null) ||    // alternative standard method
        (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen);
    var page = document.documentElement;
    if(!fsmode) {
        if(page.requestFullscreen) {
            page.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (page.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            page.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (page.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            page.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
        document.getElementById("toggle-fs").innerHTML = '<img src="/images/nofs.png">';
    } else {
        if (page.exitFullscreen) {
            page.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (page.msExitFullscreen) {
            page.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (page.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            page.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (page.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            page.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
        document.getElementById("toggle-fs").innerHTML = '<img src="/images/fs.png">';
    }
}
```

On the first click after page load, it works correctly and puts the page in fullscreen and switches the button to the exit fullscreen image.

On the second click, it replaces the image for the button but does not exit fullscreen. (Hitting 'ESC' still works.)

Any following clicks do nothing at all. So it is stuck in fullscreen with the go to fullscreen button.

This behavior is in Chrome 56.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here?

Comment: You need to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreen for further details. I believe you've to use webkitIsFullScreen instead of mozFullScreen to achieve the desired results in Chrome

Comment: The function does use webkitIsFullScreen as well as ms and moz as it needs to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions to request full screen, such as `webkitRequestFullScreen`, are on `document.documentElement`, but the ones to exit full screen, such as `webkitExitFullscreen`, are just on `document`.  The snippet below should work properly on all browsers, even IE.

Note that there are some occasions where you won't be able to enter and exit full screen.  Some examples are if the browser is running on a tablet, if the user already entered full screen themselves, or if *allowfullscreen* isn't true for an `iframe`.

```js
function canToggleFullscreen() {
  return !!(document.fullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.msFullscreenEnabled);
}
/** return true if fullScreenElement exists, indicating the document is in full screen mode. */
function isFullscreen() {
  return !!(document.fullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement);
}

/** If the browser is capable, requests to be in full screen mode. */
function enterFullscreen() {
  var page = document.documentElement
  const fullScreenFn = page.requestFullscreen || page.webkitRequestFullscreen || page.msRequestFullscreen;
  if (fullScreenFn) {
    fullScreenFn.apply(page);
  }
}

/** If the browser is capable, exits full screen mode */
function exitFullscreen() {
  const exitFullScreenFn = document.exitFullScreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen || document.msExitFullscreen;
  if (exitFullScreenFn) {
    exitFullScreenFn.apply(document);
  }
}

/** Toggles between full screen modes.  The changing of inner text */
function toggleFS() {
  if (!canToggleFullscreen()) {
    document.getElementById("toggle-fs").innerText = 'Full Screen Unavailable';
  }
  if (!isFullscreen()) {
    enterFullscreen();
    document.getElementById("toggle-fs").innerText = 'Cancel Full Screen';
  } else {
    exitFullscreen();
    document.getElementById("toggle-fs").innerText = 'Enter Full Screen';
  }
}
```

### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5t3wc28/3/)

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. Can I expect this to work in Safari as well? They no longer have a Windows version so it's difficult for me to test.

Comment: Going by the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) documentation, I expect it will since it uses the webkit prefixes.

Comment: For some reason this does not work if you press f11 then try to exit by pressing the button

Comment: @Lerex, There are lots of reasons why this could happen.  I updated my answer to include some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<button id="toggle-fs" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"><img src="/images/nofs.png"></button>
```

with...

```
document.getElementById("toggle-fs").style.display = "block";
```

Good luck!